# Publishing Not Working for item rename or change template

Tags: publishing

Using Sitecore 8.2 Update 3

I had the following folder structure in templates:

```
-User Defined
--Global
--User Defined
    --|--Core
    --|--Site Specific
    --|--|--Site 1
    --|--|--Site 2
```

I did some reorganization, so now my Master database looks like this:

```
-User Defined
--Core
--User Defined
    --|--Site Specific
    --|--|--Site 1
    --|--|--Site 2
```

When I published (republish) it seemed to move everything around OK, but it wont rename the Global folder to Core, so my web actually looks like this:

```
-User Defined
--Global
--User Defined
    --|--Site Specific
    --|--|--Site 1
    --|--|--Site 2
```

In another instance, I changed the template of an item, and that does not seem to want to publish either.

Comment: There is an issue reported for that version which affects publishing. You'll need to upgrade to 8.2u4 or use the Sitecore Publishing Service. https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update4/Release%20Notes

Comment: For these publishing issues in 8.2 u3, Sitecore has released a patch which you should integrate. Please refer [here](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6293989603787575296)

Comment: @SivaSankar Can add that as an answer?

Comment: @EthanSchofer please mark suitable suggestion if you find it as answer which would be useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Siva Sankar - I downloaded the Hotfix and this fixed the problem. The only downside is that the hotfix is an updated Sitecore.Kernell.dll, which means I am no longer using the NuGet feed for Sitecore.Kernell.dll.

Comment: Upgrade to Update 5, then you can use the feed again.

Comment: Not a viable solution at this stage of development